# ARCore NDK API questions

Tags: android-ndk, arcore

From looking at https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c
some things are not clear to me

1. Method ArPointCloud_getData mentioned at https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/ar-point-cloud#arpointcloud_getdata says that

> "Each point is represented by four consecutive values in the array; first the X, Y, Z position coordinates, followed by a confidence value."

- Question: What about the unique point IDs (identifiers)? They are not included in the output from this method?
- Question: Is there a convenience method for taking four float values and using them to construct a new ArPoint object including the pose of the point ?

2. Method ArPointCloud_getPointIds mentioned at https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/ar-point-cloud#arpointcloud_getpointids says that

> "Each point has a unique identifier (within a session) that is persistent across frames. That is, if a point from Point Cloud 1 has the same id as the point from Point Cloud 2, then it represents the same point in space."

- Question: How can a unique identifier (point id) be used to get the X, Y, Z, confidence level for a single unique point ?

Comment: Have you tried calling both functions and treating the IDs and coordinates at the same position in their respective arrays as related?

Comment: Not yet.  Good suggestion.  It would be nice if that was clear in their documentation.